# Angular 7 reactive - dropdown dynamically added to FormArray displays error too soon

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have a form in which a user can click a button and add a new FormGroup to a FormArray.

The typescript:

```
public addOutput() {
    const outputs = this.userForm.controls.controllerOutputArray as FormArray;
    var formGroup = this.fb.group({
      controllerOutputID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    })    
    outputs.push(formGroup);   
  }
```

The controllerOutputID control is bound to a dropdown list. Everything works fine, except that the dropdown list is showing an error (i.e., it is all Red) as soon as I add the control. A value is indeed required, but I don't want to show any error indications until the user interacts with the control, or tries to submit the form. My question is: How can I accomplish this?

When I inspect the value of the control, it is showing as pristine and untouched, so I don't know why the error is showing immediately.

I have tried setting errors to null:

```
formGroup.controls.controllerOutputID.setErrors(null);
```

But it makes no difference.

Can anyone help?

In case the html is useful, here it is, in relevant part:

```
 <div *ngFor="let output of userForm.controls.controllerOutputArray.controls; let i=index"
                   [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'auto'" appearance="legacy">
                  <mat-label>Selected Output</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="controllerOutputID"  required >
                    <mat-option [value]="option.id" *ngFor="let option of selectOptionLists.controllerOutputs"> {{option.name}} </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the other formControl methods like controllerOutputID.markAsPristine() ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem here was that I was using a button to invoke the addOutput method, and by default buttons are treated as form submitters - so, this triggered the validation.

I fixed it by adding type="button" to the button control:

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addOutput()" >Add New</button>
```

After that change, the validation was no longer triggered, and all worked as expected.